# Is there is any way to convert HTML to PDF?

Tags: java, pdf-generation

I tried everything but not able to find any solution.  I used iText, flying-saucer for converting HTML to PDF, but not able to do so.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;

import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;


public class Pdf {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {
         String File_To_Convert = "WebContent/index.html";
         String url = new File(File_To_Convert).toURI().toURL().toString();
         System.out.println(""+url);
         String HTML_TO_PDF = "ConvertedFile.pdf";
         OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(HTML_TO_PDF); 


         ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
         renderer.setDocument(url);      
         renderer.layout();
         renderer.createPDF(os);       
         os.close();
    }
}
```

Error while running this piece of code:

```
 Flying Saucer: No configuration files found in classpath using URL: resources/conf/xhtmlrenderer.conf, resorting to hard-coded fallback properties.
```

Comment: plz show what have you tried..

Comment: public class Pdf {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {
      String File_To_Convert = "WebContent/index.html";
         String url = new File(File_To_Convert).toURI().toURL().toString();
         System.out.println(""+url);
         String HTML_TO_PDF = "ConvertedFile.pdf";
         OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(HTML_TO_PDF); 
         
         
         ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
         renderer.setDocument(url);      
         renderer.layout();
         renderer.createPDF(os);       
         os.close();
    }
}

Comment: WARNING: Flying Saucer: No configuration files found in classpath using URL: resources/conf/xhtmlrenderer.conf, resorting to hard-coded fallback properties.

Comment: @user2681809 you can add this to your question. Your code will be more readable

Answer (score 4):

I use `ITextRenderer`. I just support `xhtml` to `pdf`. That's why your need to convert `html` to `xhtml` at first.

`xhtml` to `pdf`

```
    String path_xhtml = "C:\example.xhtml";
    String path_pdf = "C:\example.pdf";
    String url = new File(path_xhtml).toURI().toURL().toString();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(path_pdf);
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocument(url);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(os);
```

`html` to `xhtml` by `org.w3c.tidy.Tidy`

```
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\example.html");
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\example.xhtml");   
     Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
     tidy.setXHTML(true);
     Document d = tidy.parseDOM(fis, fos);
```

**update**

**Image on html file**

There might be image on html file. The above code not enought to render image.
Please reference 
   [Using Flying Saucer to Render Images to PDF In Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477065/using-flying-saucer-to-render-images-to-pdf-in-memory)